# Question sorting for unregistered sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, sorting

What is the reason/intention behind not allowing unregistered users to sort questions by categories like 'votes', 'active' etc. ? Questions are sorted by only the 'newest' type of sort.

I visit many SE sites and it is really not useful if I create an account only to visit once and never use it again.